# Can anyone tell me the time complexity of this code for sorting a list?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

This is my attempt to sort a list but I am not certain that it is correct. If it is correct, what is the time complexity? Is there a better solution?

My code:

```
class MyStackSort:
MIN = list()
MAX = list()

def sort(self, my_list):
    for index, num in enumerate(my_list):
        if self.MIN:
            if self.MIN[0] >= num:
                self.MIN = [num] + self.MIN

            elif self.MIN[-1] == num:
                self.MIN = self.MIN + [num]

            elif self.MIN[0] < num and self.MIN[-1] > num:
                for ind, min_n in enumerate(self.MIN):
                    if ind != 0 and min_n == num or self.MIN[ind-1] < num < self.MIN[ind]:
                        self.MIN = self.MIN[:ind] + [num] + self.MIN[ind:]
                        break
        elif not index == 0 and num != my_list[index-1]:
            self.MIN += [num]

        if self.MAX:
            if self.MAX[-1] <= num:
                self.MAX += [num]

            elif self.MAX[0] == num:
                self.MAX = [num] + self.MAX 

            elif self.MAX[0] < num < self.MAX[-1]:
                for ind, max_n in enumerate(self.MAX):
                    if ind != 0 and max_n == num or self.MAX[ind-1] < num < self.MAX[ind]:
                        self.MAX = self.MAX[:ind] + [num] + self.MAX[ind:]
                        break
        else:
            self.MAX += [num]

    return self.MIN + self.MAX
```

Comment: If you want to know whether the code is correct, write some unit tests for it and pass it different arrays (e.g., empty, sorted, reverse sorted, unsorted) and check that the result is what you expect. Also make sure your question title matches the description, are you asking about correctness or complexity? What is your take on the complexity? What would make other code "better" in your opinion? Please check also [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This sorting algorithm isn't correct. Here's a counter-example of a list which it does not sort correctly.

```
a = [1, 2]
sorter = MyStackSort()
print(sorter.sort(a))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 2]
```